# Always getting empty Wifi scanResult on Nexus 6

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I created a project to get available hotspots. It works well on versions older than Android 6.0. But when using the Nexus (Android 6) the scan result is **always empty**.

Anyone knows where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen in two cases
1. When your **compiled SDK** version is 22 or below. 
2. Or your compiled SDK is 23 and the use has explicitly denied the location permission to your app when it asked for it in Marshmallow.